# The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/tor+http could not be found

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a problem on rasperry pi jessie when I try to run `sudo apt-get update`:

```
The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/tor+http could not be found.
```

my sources.list

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [`apt-transport-tor`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/apt-transport-tor):

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-tor
```

> APT transport for anonymous package downloads via Tor
>
> Provides support in APT for downloading packages anonymously via the Tor network.

Debian: [Using Tor with Apt](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Using_Tor_with_Apt)

> Apt can retrieve and download updates through Tor. For this to work you need to install the `tor` and `apt-transport-tor` packages. You can then use [the official onion services](https://onion.debian.org/) provided by Debian.

Comment: I don't want to use tor, I wanna use normal http. I can't also install apt-transport-tor either, I'm using rasperry pi without tor

Comment: @andreahmed Check the 3rd party sources under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` by disabling them.

Comment: I tried the command above but it can not find the package

Comment: @andreahmed did you have some files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` ? if yes do `rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` then run `apt update`.

Comment: I removed and run apt update and it stucks at Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
100% [4 Sources xz 0 B]

Comment: @andreahmed Try to replace `mirrordirector.raspbian.org` with `archive.raspbian.org` then run `apt update`.